# set super product attributes 'Attribute Name' to 'use default '

Tags: magento, attributes

How can i change programmatically for all configurable products 'Attribute Name' use default ? I need to checked options. The place where I want to checked is marked in red
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDktq.png

Comment: Can u describe ur problem more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like what you're trying to do is remove an attribute value for certain products at a certain store scope (in which case it will fall back to 'use default' mode and acquire the next attribute value available , whether that be defined at the website level or global level). You need to remove the value entries from the entity value table (e.g. catalog_product_entity_varchar) where the attribute ID and store ID match the ones you're trying to remove. You could do it with raw SQL fairly easily:

```
DELETE from your_entity_valuetype WHERE attribute_id=X and store_id=Y;
```

Plug in your attribute ID (you can grab that from the eav_attribute table) and store ID, and the [table for the attribute value](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-7-advanced-orm-entity-attribute-value).

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a old post, but as it is still seems to be unsolved I thought I would add this for the next person that comes looking.

The table you need to update is `catalog_product_super_attribute_label` you will see a value for all products. If you update this table to 'use_default' as 1 this will check the box and use the default attribute label.

I hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Thanks Nathan this is very helpful and should really be the accepted answer which currently is both confusing and wrong.

If anyone wants to just set all their super product attributes to use the default label (as defined at attribute level) then this would do the trick:

````UPDATE `catalog_product_super_attribute_label` SET `use_default` = 1;````